# Webform submit button disappearing if I change it from default

Tags: webforms

I have a weird issue with the webform module, whenever I modify the submit button (change text, add class) it doesn't show up on the page anymore (nor in the source code). If I delete it, it is back to default (the label in the OPERATION column says customize again) and it works, but it disappear if I change it again.

I didn't do any weird modification beside creating a Twig template for it. But since it works when I leave it to its default value I doubt the issue lies there.
Hopefully one of you guys can help me.

Here is the YAML code:

```
markup:
  '#type': markup
  '#markup': |
    <h2>
      Je publie une offre d'emploi
    </h2>
job:
  '#type': textfield
  '#title': job
  '#title_display': invisible
  '#placeholder': 'Fonction recherchée*'
  '#required': true
  '#required_error': 'Fill in a valid job'
  '#pattern': '^[a-zA-Z]*$'
company:
  '#type': textfield
  '#title': company
  '#title_display': invisible
  '#placeholder': 'Nom de la société*'
  '#required': true
  '#required_error': 'Fill in a company'
  '#pattern': '^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$'
job_description:
  '#type': textarea
  '#title': 'job description'
  '#title_display': invisible
  '#placeholder': 'Description de la fonction'
  '#required': true
  '#required_error': 'Fill in a description'
contract:
  '#type': select
  '#title': contract
  '#title_display': invisible
  '#options':
    CDD: CDD
    CDI: CDI
  '#empty_value': 'Type de contrat*'
  '#required': true
  '#required_error': 'Choose a contract type'
job_schedule:
  '#type': select_other
  '#title': 'job schedule'
  '#title_display': invisible
  '#options':
    'Full time': 'Full time'
    'Part time': 'Part time'
  '#empty_value': 'Travail à temps...*'
  '#required': true
  '#required_error': 'Select a schedule'
location:
  '#type': textfield
  '#title': location
  '#title_display': invisible
  '#placeholder': 'Lieu*'
  '#required': true
publication_date:
  '#type': date
  '#title': 'publication date'
  '#description': 'Date de publication*'
  '#title_display': invisible
  '#description_display': before
  '#prepopulate': true
  '#required': true
  '#required_error': 'Select a publication day'
  '#min': today
  '#max': '+2 months'
  '#step': '1'
end_date:
  '#type': date
  '#title': 'end date'
  '#description': 'Date limite*'
  '#title_display': invisible
  '#description_display': before
  '#required': true
  '#min': '+2 weeks'
url:
  '#type': url
  '#title': URL
  '#title_display': invisible
  '#placeholder': 'URL: RH ou Plateforme pour postuler*'
  '#required': true
  '#required_error': 'Fill in a valid URL'
phone:
  '#type': tel
  '#title': phone
  '#description': 'Mes informations (pour &ecirc;tre contact&eacute; par BioWin)'
  '#title_display': invisible
  '#description_display': before
  '#placeholder': 'Numéro de téléphone*'
email:
  '#type': email
  '#title': email
  '#title_display': invisible
  '#placeholder': 'Adresse email'
  '#pattern': '^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,10})+$'
actions:
  '#type': webform_actions
  '#title': 'Submit button(s)'
  '#submit__label': Envoyer
  '#submit__attributes':
    class:
      - cta
```

Comment: Can you please post the webform's source YAML so that we can reproduce the issue? Are you using the latest release of the webform module?

Comment: I updated the post, I'm using the version 8.x-5.0-rc1 which was the latest at the start of the project I'm working on

Comment: I am not seeing any issues with Drupal 8.5.x and Webform 8.x-5.0-rc3 + with the Bartik theme.  Are you able to reproduce the issue using the Bartik theme and/or https://simplytest.me?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the fact that I'm using a custom theme, thanks for helping anyway, I'll just leave it default and force some style on it

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom twig template for your webform the custom submit button needs to be referenced differently than the default.

Default Submit Button reference:

{{ element.actions }}

Customized Submit Button reference:

{{ element.elements.actions }}